# =HOUR formula not working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

im trying to get only the hour from the time but when i try to do it i get **0:00:00**

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw1rX.png)

i tried to change time Locale to United Kingdom but still i get the same error

[ScreenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHWMz.png)

the same formula work in excel just fine but i don't know why i get this problem in google sheets.
Please any help

Comment: Are they true time or values entered as text? It they text the use `LEFT()` function.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=LEFT(TO_TEXT(G2); 2)
```

or:

```
=TEXT(G2; "hh")
```